# nasm .c and .asm file linking

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm

I am trying to link a c program and a .asm file(nasm).
Starting with a simple program to print a helloworld, am not even able to do that. The coding and compilation steps are shown below :

hello.asm file

```
extern sample    

section .text
global main
main:

call sample
mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 80h
```

cfile.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void sample()
{
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

Compilation Steps:

```
jincy@jincy:~/codes/nasm$ nasm -f elf64 hello.asm
jincy@jincy:~/codes/nasm$ gcc -c cfile.c
jincy@jincy:~/codes/nasm$ gcc cfile.o hello.o
jincy@jincy:~/codes/nasm$ ./a.out
jincy@jincy:~/codes/nasm$
```

I tried looking online for a solution, but couldnt find it. Can anyone help me out to contiue with this?

Comment: You messed that up horribly. What is `fib.o` anyway? You have `hello.asm` you probably want `hello.o` there. Also the error says you have a `main` defined in `cfile.c`, double check your source file.

Comment: @Jester Sorry. Now corrected those. Yes,there was a main function. I removed it now. Got through the compilation part. But no output.

Comment: See, now it's better! Okay, you should not use the exit syscall in your asm because that doesn't shut down the c library properly. You should just `ret`, or use `call exit`.  Then you will see the output. You will probably also see it if you add a `\n` to your `printf` because output is line buffered.